# Cron file working fine in browser but not in command

Tags: php, cron, command

I have configured cron job in hostgator.
It runs from web browser just fine and everything works.
(https://www.site.com/cron.php)
But the scheduled cron job in hostgator does not work with any of these command...
php /home/username/public_html/cron.php
or php -q /home/username/public_html/cron.php

Here is my cron.php file. Can you help?

```
<?php
    require_once ('config_inc.php');


    define('_VALID_MOS_', 1);
    set_time_limit(0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    require_once (DOCSPATH . 'includes/eg_cron.php');

    if (running_from_commandline()){
        run_cronfile();
        exit;
    }
    require_once (DOCSPATH . 'includes/setting_inc.php');
    require_once (_EG_LANGUAGE_DIR . $config['language_default']  . "/general.php");
    $cron = new egCron();

    if ($config['cron_investment']) $cron->cron_deposit();
    if ($config['mailqueue_enable'] && $config['cron_mailqueue']) $cron->cron_mailqueue();
    if ($config['cron_automail']) $cron->cron_automail();

    if ($config['expdays'] && $config['cron_expire']) $cron->cron_expire();
    if ($config['cron_pending']) $cron->cron_pending();
    if ($config['cron_stats']) $cron->cron_stats();

    $cron->log_cron("Cron job finished successfully");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We faced same issue here are alternatives you an try.
In include give full absolute path instead of relative.
Try using php-cgi instead of php

And enjoy.